# Как заставить работать cups ipp принтер в Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows

Не могу установить принтер через IPP

> http: //host:631/printers/EPSON_Stylus_Photo_R290

Проблема именно в windows 10.
В xp проблем нет.
Принтер подключен к Debian с использованием cups.

Вручную указываю драйвер, но при попытке печатать да же тестовую страницу тишина. В очереди cups пусто.
Проблема явно в windows 10, до переустановки в 7 такой проблемы не было.
Компонент IPP установлен, проверял.
В реестр добавлял PreferredConnection=0.
Безрезультатно.